# How to reverse the order of each two consecutive elements in a vector?

Tags: r, vector, reverse

Let's say I have the following vector

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I wish to reverse the order of each two consecutive elements as follows

```
2 1 4 3 6 5
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried to use the function `rev` and to create a function to automatise my work but couldn' find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave` + `rev` to reverse the vector by group:

```r
ave(x, (seq_along(x) + 1) %/% 2, FUN = rev)
#[1] 2 1 4 3 6 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea,

```
c(rbind(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)], x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
# [1] 2 1 4 3 6 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do

```
as.vector(matrix(x, nrow = 2)[2:1, ])

[1] 2 1 4 3 6 5
```

Comment: `c` works also here instead of `as.vector`

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```r
x[seq_along(x) + c(1, -1)]
# [1] 2 1 4 3 6 5
```